# socket.io client side in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i am using socket.io for communication between server and client.
My client side is not a html. My client side is javascript file. so here is my code of client side

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/home');

socket.on('connect', function () {

    console.log(' Connected!');
});
```

On server side i have received the connection event but on client side connect event doesn't fire. I have tested through html way, it works but why its not working through a java script file.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that your client side is not html?

Comment: show us the server code

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean with tested through html way, but try `socket.on("connection", ...)`,
not "connect".

Answer (score 0):

could be related to the fact that you're specifying a namespace different from the default.
try to handle the connection at http://localhost:3000, instead of http://localhost:3000/home

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

found a similar situation [**here**](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/255)